# Workshop: What to put on CV when you had multiple roles?

Tags: cv

Part of my post-doc has involved organizing a series of workshops. At some of these workshops, I end up with many roles. As an example, for the most recent workshop I wrote the proposal to get the funding, served as organizer, gave a talk/tutorial related to my research, and gave a (teaching) tutorial on some general skills useful in the field. (These workshops are more like schools: teaching grad students and post-docs about best practices.)

My question is: What parts should end up on my CV, and where? It feels ridiculous if some workshops show up 3 or 4 times (under headings for funded proposals, workshop organization, and talks). On the other hand, it was all a lot of work.

In addition, there were some workshops where I only gave a talk, and some where I was an organizer, but didn't write the funding proposal. It seems weird to include a talk from the one where I wasn't an organizer, and not include a talk that served the same purpose when I **was** an organizer.

What's the standard/recommended practice in this case? For context, my work is at the border of chemistry and physics, so to the extent that a lot of CV stuff is domain-specific, those are the relevant domains.

Comment: Who was the audience?  If you give a talk about your research to people from your university, that is very different from giving a talk about your research to people from other universities.

Comment: Academic CVs regularly have a funding section, maybe list such activities there, rather than under event organisation.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can create a heading for "Workshop Experience", "Workshop Facilitated" or something along these lines. Then include all your workshop experiences there. You may have responsibilities such as:

- Wrote the proposal for the initial funding and organization of the workshop
- Gave a talk on ... (if needed to include the talk's name)
- Reviewing submissions
- Serving on committees (or lead sessions)
- Coordinating and organizing events and conferences
- Making ...
- ...

You may also modify the format above and in front of each activity, name the workshops where you did that task.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I am not from your field so YMMV.

Assuming that you are applying for an academic position, the first order of business in any CV should be awards/research, followed by teaching experience, followed by professional service. What you're describing sounds like it falls under professional service. Did you have an official title in these workshops? If so, I'd list it as

Workshop of Physical Chemistry

- Title1 (2017)
- Title2 (2018)

and so on. If you chaired a workshop, and it's a known/prestigious workshop in your field, then just knowing your role would give people all the information they need (in my field chairs manage the program, decide the schedule, invite speakers etc. so I don't need to start detailing my roles, it's common knowledge). If it's not a very well-known workshop or doesn't follow the standard in your field for some reason, I would either not list it since it's not sufficiently important, or perhaps (if you feel it's important enough) say one sentence.

I would not put teaching roles in professional workshops as part of your teaching experience (unless they're really a summer school mini-course). You can reflect ad consolidate these things in your teaching statement.

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Group *funding* and *organizer* into a single title, list them under the *service* section of your CV (which will also include reviewing activities, for instance), and describe your role there.

Whether you list *research* and *tutorial talks* depends on whether you have a *presentations* section. Both can be listed if so. Alternatively, both could be listed in the *publications* section, if they were accompanied by manuscripts that appeared in any workshop proceedings.

As careers progress, *presentation* sections get dropped and  *invited talks* sections get added. (If either or both of your talks were invited talks, then list them in such a section, they're considered prestigious.)